# Где правильнее задать настройки для node сервера на nginx

Tags: sql, node.js, веб-программирование, nginx, http

Не могу найти полный ответ на 1 вопрос: Где всё же правильно настраивать сервер nginx для простого node js сервера, который просто обрабатывает http запросы от клиентов и возвращает им ответ. Подключение будет через IP, поэтому домен не нужен, как и html страница.

В одних источниках(гайды по созданию простого сервера) пишут про настройку файла в `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`, в других же говориться о `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Что я хочу сделать:
На моей удалённой Ubuntu будет расположен NodeJS сервер, который получает http запросы от клиента-игры на UE4 и отправляет назад ответы (Авторизовать пользователя, зарегистрировать и т.п.).
Основной игровой сервер будет на UE, где игрок выступает хостом, web сервер же просто будет хранит БД с игроками, токенами и списком запущенных серверов.

Comment: Где вам удобнее, там и пишите

Comment: @andreymal, кстати, чертовски прав. Различие в том, что в `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` есть строчка `include` которая указывает на другие конфигурации. Если вы используете `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`, то вам скорей всего надо линковать в `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`.

Comment: Первые гайды рассчитаны на debian-подобные дистры (Ubuntu и тп), вторые на какие-то другие